# Time manipulation in Swift

Tags: swift, time

i'm looking to do some time manipulation in swift. Mainly subtracting and adding.

Scenario:
Time to work
Start Time in morning
End Time in morning
Start time in afternoon

Calculated end time for the day-

so far i have, which gives me an idea about the worked time in the morning:

```
let diffMorning = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: tmMorningFrom.date, to: tmMorningTo.date)
let Morninghours = diffMorning.hour
let Morningminutes = diffMorning.minute
    
tmResult.text =  "\nWorked time in morning: \(String(describing: Morninghours!)) Hours \(String(describing: Morningminutes!)) Minutes"
```

Question:
how to i subtract time ? I need now to subtracted the worked time in the morning from the field (Time to Work) and add the result to the field 'Start time in afternoon' which gives me the end result.

thanks for input - seems time manipulation is not that easy ;-)

[image]

Comment: To do date math, use DateComponents and Calendar.

Comment: what is Time To Work and since you started using Calendar why not continue with it?

Comment: all this fields are coming from UIDatePicker     Time to work
Start Time in morning
End Time in morning
Start time in afternoon

Comment: it's the first time i'm planning with time in swift - having been doing a lot of searches and getting confused by different methods .. i'm new in swift have only back expertise in old school programming ;-)

Comment: Ok, old school is fine. Please provide actual input and desired / expected output.

Comment: Thanks Matt   - Input are the fields on the screenshot above - output is the expected end time for today.   So user defines the number of hours to work - define start time and end time in the morning, and the start time in the afternoon - app calculates the end working time

Comment: Hi, anyone idea or tip to help me forward ?